# C++ map to type for creation

Tags: c++, glm-math

I am not sure how to do this in C++ ... and so I would like to seek the knowledge of the Stack :)

Basically I have an enum defining some values I care about:

```
enum class VertexField : uint16_t
{
    Position = 0,
    Color,
    Normal,
    Count,
    Invalid
};
```

Then I have an array that indicates the size of each enum if we allocate memory for that enum value:

```
const uint16_t sFieldSizes[] =
{
    12,     //Position, 4bytes each, float vec3
    4,      //Color, 1bytes each, unorm vec4
    12      //Normal, 4bytes each, float vec3
};
```

Now what I want to do is to add another array that tells me the type ... so conceptually it would look like:

```
const TYPE sFieldTypes[] = 
{
    glm::vec3,
    uint32_t,
    glm::vec3
};
```

I know the above isn't code that works but what are ways to do what I want that compiles?

Comment: Try changing your design.  The C++ language does not support reflection.

Comment: For example, instead of have a function that operates base on field types, modify the field classes (types) to contain the functionality.

Comment: I was hoping some macro + template magic :) not looking for general reflection system.

Comment: You can use some template magic:  `template< typename DataType> function(...)`.   You'll need to override the function name for POD types.

Comment: Adding some macro to the ill-designed code will make you crazy one day.

Comment: Might be worth looking into [boost::hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @SmitYcyken what’s a better design?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon, this is typical XY question. It looks like you are trying to invent one more reflection bicycle in c++.

Comment: Also if all of your types are default constructible, you might be able to do some hackery with `std::tuple`, e.g. with C++17: `using sFieldTypes = std::tuple<glm::vec3, uint32_t, glm::vec3>; std::apply([](auto val){ /* something with decltype(val)... */ }, sFieldTypes{});`